# Python count the frequency of each number in a list without any count() functions or without importing anything

Tags: python

Lets say I have List `myList = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]`
I want to count the frequency of each number in the list and make it into some sort of graph with an output:

```
1: X X
2: X X X
3: X
```

But I can't figure it out. I'm very new to Python and i need to make the code without any built in functions and without using import to import anything

Comment: without built-in functions?

Comment: have yout tried something? do you have an idea of how you would do it? or what you would try (even if you don't know how)?

Comment: Even print is a function in Python 3.x. BTW, what Python version?

Comment: Try using a loop and a dictionary to keep track of how many you've seen for each number.

Comment: I only really meant the count function

Comment: And is it possible to do it without using dictionaries?

Comment: @AlexRochford yes, but it is very inefficient

Comment: I'm not worried about efficiency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dict`-based solution:

```
myList = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
output = {}

for item in myList:
    if item not in output:
        output[item] = 0
    output[item] += 1
```

Then, print it:

```
for number, count in output.iteritems():
    print "{0}: {1}".format(number, "X " * count)
```

Comment: im getting this error:  for number, count in output.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @AlexRochford You're on Python 3. replace `iteritems` with `items`. Reason: In python2, `items` returned a list, `iteritems` returned a iterator. In python3 `items` returns a iterator and `iteritems` doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok i changed it but it only prints out one element. So myList = [5, 5, 5, 6, 6] and it only prints 5: X X X

Answer (score 1):

Anyway Python standard lib have a proper module to that, [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> myList = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
>>> print Counter(myList)
Counter({2: 3, 1: 2, 3: 1})
```

Comment: "without any built in functions and without using import to import anything" - from OP question.

Answer (score 0):

This work without any count function

```
freq =[0]*1001
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
        for i in arr:
            freq[i] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

#without using any built in functions

```
def fre(my_list):
    
    #using empty dictionary
    freq={}
    for item in my_list:
        if(item in freq):
            freq[item]+=1
        else:
            freq[item]=1
    for key,value in freq.items():
        print(f"{key}:{value}")
my_list=list(map(int,input("Enter the list elements").split()))

fre(my_list)
```